# iScroll very slow when elements of the list has :active (with opacity)

Tags: iscroll4

In my snap list,if every item has a :active style:

```
div:active{background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);}
```

then the scroller will be very slow and the page get janky when scroll the list.
I know with the translateZ(0) hack will be fine.but that would no good if too many item in my list.any suggestions?

Comment: How is the translateZ(0) hack?

Comment: I know with the translateZ(0) hack will be fine.but that would no good if too many item in my list